# How to find the missing data from table using Sql in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Every five minutes, my system will produce a file and I will store the file name in my table.

I name the file name like:

- studentA202106011940-202106011945.zip
- studentA202106011945-202106011950.zip

So in one day, I will store 288 files in my table.

Now I can search the file in some day like:

```
select * 
from studentData 
where LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fileName, '-',-1),8)='29210601'
```

How can I quickly find the missing data from table?

Comment: Please define what "missing data" means.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Write a recursive query to generate all file names, then use `NOT EXISTS` to see which ones are missing.

Comment: *How can I quickly find the missing data from table?* "Missing data" is the filename which is absent for specified data?

Comment: Write a recursive query to generate all file names ,you means to create a temp table?@ThorstenKettner

Comment: @GordonLinoff,It means that in one day I must have 12*24=288 records,If the count is not 288,then means missing data

Comment: A recursive query starts with a self-referencing `WITH` clause It is featured since MySQL version 8. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Comment: Do WITH support MYSQL 5.7.27?

Comment: No, MySQL 5.7 is old. It was MySQL 8 when they introduced this and several other features. It is worth upgrading :-)

Comment: '1945' represents the file created at 19:45?

Comment: Yes,@Strawberry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the next starttime is not the same the a given rows end time.  This identifies the *first* missing row in a sequence of adjacent missing rows:

```
with f as (
      select f.*,
             right(substring_index(filename, '-', 1), 12) as starttime,
             substring_index(substring_index(filename, '-', -1), '.', 1) as endtime
      from files f
     ) 
select f.*, f.endtime as first_missing_starttime
from (select f.*,
             lead(starttime) over (order by starttime) as next_startttime
      from f
     ) f
where f.next_starttime <> f.endtime;
```

Comment: @flower . . . This requires MySQL 8+.

Comment: I try to rewrite your sql using view.

Comment: @flower . . . This logic would be very tricky -- and expensive -- to put into a view in pre-8.0 versions of MySQL.  You might consider upgrading MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this can be written more succinctly, but anyway...

For 5.7, I have a table of integers (i) from 0 to 9...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;
CREATE TABLE my_table
(my_string CHAR(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('202106011945'),('202106011950');

SELECT SEC_TO_TIME((i4.i*1000+i3.i*100+i2.i*10+i1.i) *300) t
   FROM ints i1
   JOIN ints i2
   JOIN ints i3
   JOIN ints i4 
   LEFT
   JOIN my_table x
     ON TIME(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(x.my_string,00),'%Y%m%d%H%i%s')) = SEC_TO_TIME((i4.i*1000+i3.i*100+i2.i*10+i1.i) *300)
  WHERE i4.i*1000+i3.i*100+i2.i*10+i1.i <288
    AND x.my_string IS NULL;

+----------+
| t        |
+----------+
| 00:00:00 |
...
| 18:45:00 |
| 18:50:00 |
| 18:55:00 |
| 19:00:00 |
| 19:05:00 |
| 19:10:00 |
| 19:15:00 |
| 19:20:00 |
| 19:25:00 |
| 19:30:00 |
| 19:35:00 |
| 19:40:00 | -- we can see that
| 19:55:00 | -- it's working
| 20:00:00 |
| 20:05:00 |
...
+----------+
```

Comment: CREATE TABLE ints
(i int(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO ints VALUES
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9); I run the sql and the result is null

Comment: I don't think INT(12) is a thing. Anyway, you forgot 0